# JavaScript "this" in a function block

Tags: javascript, this

`this` refers to the object it belongs to, for example:

```
var someObj = {
  logObj : function() { return this }
}

obj.logObj() => someObj
```

and a function is an object. But then why does `this` in a function refer to the window, not the function? For example,

```
function someFunc() { return this }
```

won't `return someFunc()`, but `window`.

Comment: Those are totally different cases. If the language worked like your second example, then `someObj.logObj` would return a reference to that function, not `someObj`  Would suggest just reading one of the many guides to `this` in Javascript to be clear on the how it works.

Comment: someFunc's owner is Window because you didn't put it inside an object.

Comment: @Ryan but a function is an object.

Comment: @barry-johnson I think I know how it works, what I'm wondering is why it works that way.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

myFunc is defined on the window object since it is part of the global scope.  Any global variables are defined on the window object.  You can reference that function with `this.myFunc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true, a function is an object. However, the statements inside the function are not called with `this` set to the function itself. That would keep `this` from referencing the object that it was called on, and therefore eliminate much of the usefulness of `this`. There are ways to accomplish what you seek though.

> "When a function is called as a method of an object, the object is passed to the function as its **this** value." [ECMAScript Specification 4.3.31](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-method)

Functions are not called as methods of themselves. Functions not executed as methods of an object are called as methods of the global object (or `undefined` if in "strict" mode).

```js
function test() { 
  console.log(this == window);
}

var obj = {'test': test};

test();
window.test();
obj.test();
```

If you really want for the `this` in a function to refer to itself, then you will have to add the function as a property of itself, or use a function such as `apply`, `call`, or `bind` which have a `thisArg`.

```js
function test() { console.log(this) };

test.test = test;

test.test();
test.call(test);
test.apply(test);
test.bind(test)();
```

Comment: @JaeeunLee Are you asking for a reference to the specs? If it wasn't this way, then it would be impossible for `this` to refer to other things. Asking "why" is usually the wrong question.

Comment: *Functions executed in global scope are called as methods of window* - aren't they rather just unbound functions? Which will have this set to the global object or undefined no matter in which context they are executed?

Comment: @le_m You're right. I've clarified. Can you explain how it could be undefined though? Are you referring to portions of EMCAScript such as JScript which don't have a global object? (Yes, you heard right)

Comment: @4castle It is undefined when you `"use strict";` AFAIK

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm getting the gist of it. The answer to my question seems to be actually your first comment: "If it wasn't this way, then it would be impossible for `this` to refer to other things." Could you actually elaborate on that?

Comment: @JaeeunLee Are you familiar with any other programming language which has a `this`? I can't really think of a way to elaborate without making a comparison to Object Oriented Programming. All I can really say is that `this` wouldn't have any unique purpose if it was just a synonym for the function's name (unless maybe it was an anonymous function)

Answer (score 0):

Context is most often determined by how a function is invoked. When a function is called as a method of an object, this is set to the object the method is called on:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function(){
        alert(this === obj);    
    }
};

obj.foo(); // true
```

The same principle applies when invoking a function with the new operator to create an instance of an object. When invoked in this manner, the value of this within the scope of the function will be set to the newly created instance:

```
function foo(){
   alert(this);
}

foo() // window
new foo() // foo
```

When called as an unbound function, this will default to the global context or window object in the browser. However, if the function is executed in strict mode, the context will default to undefined.

Comment: `new foo()` does not alert `foo` here. It alerts an object with `foo` as the constructor. If you wanted it to alert `foo`, then you would need to do `foo.foo = foo; foo.foo();`

Comment: @4castle Do you read, what i wrote? "When invoked in this manner, the value of this within the scope of the function will be set to the newly created instance". That's why i not understand why you add your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to create an object - with an object literal, or with an object constructor.

Only when you use the latter technique will `this` refer to the object it occurs within.

This is how to create an object with an object constructor (in your example, a literal was used) :

```
var objConstructor = function () {
   this.logObj = function () {return this}
}

var obj1 = new objConstructor()
```

Comment: but isn't my first example (someObj) an object literal?

Comment: Exactly, that's why it didn't work. Create with Object Literal -> this refers to window (or next closest closure). Create with Object Constructor -> this refers to object.

Comment: But my first example does work-- in `someObj`, `this` refers to `someObj` even if it is an object literal.